# hypothesis testing and bayes factor

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution, bayesian, hypothesis-testing

Suppose that $[X∣p]∼Bin(15,p)$, and the goal is to test if $H_0:p∼Unif([0,0.5])$ and $H_a:p∼Unif((0.5,1])$. Suppose $X=9$, Find the evidence for $H_0, H_a$ and the Bayes factor.

In this case, the p is uniform, so is it correct to say that p for $H_0$ is $0.25$ and p for $H_a$ is $0.75$?

If so, is this correct for calculating $H_0$: $P(X=9|H_0)$ = $15\choose9$ $(.25)^{15}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bayesian model comparison, the Bayes factor is given by the [marginal likelihoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_likelihood) of the two hypotheses' ratio.
The marginal likelihood for hypothesis $H_0$ is
$$\mathbb P(X=9\mid H_0) = \int_{p\in[0,0.5]}\mathbb P(X=9\mid p,H_0)\cdot f_0(p)\ dp$$
Where $f_0$ is the density function of $p$ under hypothesis $H_0$ (i.e. $f_0(x) = 2\ \forall x$) and $\mathbb P(X=9\mid p,H_0) = {15\choose 9}p^9(1-p)^6$. Therefore
$$\mathbb P(X=9\mid H_0) = \int_{p\in[0,0.5]} {15\choose 9}p^9(1-p)^6\cdot2\ dp \approx 0.028 $$
Similarly,
$$\mathbb P(X=9\mid H_a) = \int_{p\in[0.5,1]} {15\choose 9}p^9(1-p)^6\cdot2\ dp \approx 0.097 $$
Finally, the Bayes factor is given by
$$ K = \frac{P(X=9\mid H_0)}{P(X=9\mid H_a)} \approx 0.289$$
Which seems to suggest that $H_a$ [is slightly more likely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor#Interpretation) than $H_0$

Comment: Can you explain why $f_0(p) = 2$?

Comment: [It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) that the probability density function of a $\text{Uniform}(a,b)$ random variable is $f(x) =  {{1} \over {b-a}}$. $f_0$ is the density of a $\text{Uniform}(0,1/2)$ r.v. so $f_0(x) = 2$ by the same formula